# Where can I find this old app: Biorhythms by Andrew Regan

Tags: applications

The most recent version if possible. Maybe you have it ?

The developer's site has disappeared, here's the [MacUpdate page](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/4865/biorhythms/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use [The Wayback Machine](http://www.archive.org/web/web.php). I've used it on numerous occasion to download something that doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: Worked ! [download page](http://web.archive.org/web/20031012113528/http://hiatus-uk.com/bio/downloads.jsp)

Comment: @user2113 Awesome!

Answer (score 1):

You can download it right from MacUpdate, can't you?

Comment: When I attempt to do so, I repeatedly get a network time out message:

Network Access Message: The page cannot be displayed
 Explanation: The request timed out before the page could be retrieved.

Comment: I just did a Google search for the exact file name MacUpdate links to. There you go: http://www.google.de/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=bio902_shareware.sit

Comment: @Ben, have you tried ?

Comment: @user2113 I haven't.